# Combine MERGE and INSERT ALL statment

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have an issue that could be solved by implementing full aduting either with triggers or flash data archive but that's much more than is required.

So right now we are performing a merge which is updating a row when its present or inserting when its not. It works well and was easy to write. We now have a new requirement which is that users must know which rows have been updated or inserted. Yes this could be accomplished by introducing another field into the table, but thats not allowed because that would change the table. So we are forced to create one or two tables which will identify which rows are updated or inserted via the PK.

What I am hoping to do is take the existing MERGE statement and add the ability to insert into the secondary table, but I have not been able to find any merge statements which work that way, and INSERT ALL lacks the more complicated conditionals of the merge.

Here is the structure of the MERGE statement thats currently being used.

```
 MERGE INTO EXISTING_TABLE ET USING TMP_TABLE TMP ON (HRR.ID = TMP.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    ET.ID = TMP.ID,
    ET.TITLE_EN = TMP.TITLE_EN,
    ET.TITLE_FR = TMP.TITLE_FR,
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, TITLE_EN, TITLE_FR)
    VALUES (TMP.ID, TMP.TITLE_EN, TMP.TITLE_FR);
```

Below is the way Im hoping to accomplish the MERGE INSERT ALL.

```
 MERGE INTO EXISTING_TABLE ET USING TMP_TABLE TMP ON (HRR.ID = TMP.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET
        ET.ID = TMP.ID,
        ET.TITLE_EN = TMP.TITLE_EN,
        ET.TITLE_FR = TMP.TITLE_FR,
    INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (ID, TYPE) VALUES (TMP.ID, 'U')
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ALL
    INTO EXISTING_TABLE (ID, TITLE_EN, TITLE_FR) VALUES (TMP.ID, TMP.TITLE_EN, TMP.TITLE_FR),
    INTO NEW_TABLE (ID, TYPE) VALUES (TMP.ID, 'I');
```

The only other way to reasonably accomplish this that I can see would be with a PLSQL block which works on row statements and would be slower.

Comment: @EvilTeach No.... Could you change your comment to an answer. Trigger would definitely handle what I am attempting to do and it would be straightforward and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At our site, we use after triggers to update audit stuff.  It has an advantage of tracking the changes via program, or if someone fat fingers an update statement.

That might do the job for you.

Comment: Considering that Ive worked with triggers for a few other things on this project, Im a little disappointed that I had not considered for this purpose

Comment: Right back at you.  Part of the magic of this site is that a fresh viewpoint can help blow the smoke away.   You might be able to cobble something together with INSERT/RETURNING, but like you said.  It is clean and easy with a trigger